# Invalid content type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded on request using httparty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httparty

I'm sending a post request to intuit(merchant account) using httparty gem.

Here's my code:

```
header = {"Content-Type" => "application/xml", 
          "content-length" => request.length 
         };

options = { :body => request,:options=>{ :headers => header} }
data = HTTParty.post(url,options)
```

Now event though I'm sending content-type as `application/xml` The response error is:

```
 #<HTTParty::Response:0x44278 parsed_response="Invalid content type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded.\n", @response=#<Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request readbody=true>, @headers={"date"=>["Fri, 16 Aug 2013 15:49:50 GMT"], "server"=>["Apache"], "content-length"=>["57"], "connection"=>["close"], "content-type"=>["text/plain"]}
```

I have no Idea what I'm doing wrong. Any Idea?

Here's the output for data.request.inspect:

```
#<HTTParty::Request:0x0000000440be98 @http_method=Net::HTTP::Post, @path=#<URI::HTTPS:0x00000bba0 URL:https://merchantaccount.ptc.quickbooks.com/j/AppGateway>, @options={:limit=>5, :default_params=>{}, :follow_redirects=>true, :parser=>HTTParty::Parser, :connection_adapter=>HTTParty::ConnectionAdapter, :body=>"<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>\n<?qbmsxml version=\"2.0\"?>\n<QBMSXML>\n<SignonMsgsRq>\n<SignonAppCertRq>\n<ClientDateTime>\#{today}</ClientDateTime>\n<ApplicationLogin>\#{APPLICATION_LOGIN} </ApplicationLogin>\n<ConnectionTicket><\#{CONNECTION_TICKET}</ConnectionTicket>\n<Language>English</Language>\n<AppID>\#{APPLICATION_ID }</AppID>\n<AppVer>1</AppVer>\n</SignonAppCertRq>\n</SignonMsgsRq>\n</QBMSXML>", :options=>{:headers=>{"Content-Type"=>"application/xml", "standalone"=>"yes", "encoding"=>"UTF-8", "content-length"=>379}}}, @last_uri=#<URI::HTTPS:0x0000000440afe8 URL:https://merchantaccount.ptc.quickbooks.com/j/AppGateway>, @raw_request=#<Net::HTTP::Post POST>, @last_response=#<Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request readbody=true>>
```

Comment: can you `inspect` request and provide its contents?

Comment: THanks. can you change `:body => request` to `:body => request.body`. I think passing whole request object is confusing HTTParty and makes it override the content-type.

Comment: I'm getting undefined method `body' for #<String:0x00000003f3eaf0>

Comment: make sure you do `request.body` and not `request.inspect.body`. according to your post, I thought `request` object was HTTParty object and not string.

Comment: Ah request is just a simple variable name which contains xml data in string format.

Comment: can you please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773939/can-someone-provide-an-example-for-how-to-post-xml-using-httparty-and-ruby-on-ra and see if it helps? `format :xml` might be what you are missing.

Answer (score 1):

That should probably be:

```
data = HTTParty.post(url, :body => request, :headers => {"Content-Type" => "application/xml"})
```

Don't worry about content-length, that's HTTParty's job.